# WordPress, письма с заявок попадают в папку Спама

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, email

Сайт на **WordPress**, хостинг и домен сайта находятся на **REG.RU**, домен кириллический. Заявки с формы обратной связи приходят, но почему-то попадают в папку Спам.

Отправку заявок пробовал делать на почту **Mail.ru** и **Google**, в обоих случаях попадали в спам. **PHP** обработчик использовал свой, поместил его в корне установки **WordPress**, код вот ниже предоставил. Также пробовал отправлять через плагин **Contact Form 7**, там тоже письма в спам идут.

Уже не знаю что делать, подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить эту проблему?

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
$name = htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"]);
$tel = htmlspecialchars($_POST["phone"]);
$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST["email"]);
$refferer = getenv('HTTP_REFERER');
$date = date("d.m.y"); // число.месяц.год
$time = date("H:i"); // часы:минуты:секунды
$myemail = "sergey_5550199@mail.ru";
$tema = "Новый заказ";
$message_to_myemail = "Уважаемый администратор, Вам поступил новый заказ
<br><br>
Имя: $name<br>
Телефон: $tel<br>
Источник (ссылка): $refferer<br>
";


mail( $myemail, $tema, $message_to_myemail, "Reply-To: Davydov-Event 
\r\n"."MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"."Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n" 
);


$tema = "Заказ принят";
$message_to_myemail = "
Спасибо, Ваш заказ успешно принят
";
$myemail = $email;
mail($myemail, $tema, $message_to_myemail, "From: Davydov-Event \r\n Reply- 
To: Davydov-Event \r\n"."MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"."Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n" );
```

Comment: А если изменить content type ?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский никак не связано со спамом

Comment: @KAGGDesign  не знал ... но вроде бы в основах php где было это что изменение Сontent-type влияет ... а  может я ошибаюсь

Comment: 1. Используй плагины, а не дырявые самописные формы. 2. Настрой правильно SPF, DKIM, DMARC. 3. Если с такой формы уходит почта - хостинг дырявый.  Менять нафик! А да.. это же регру. Менять, менять срочно!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут несколько уровней проблем.

Не используйте функцию mail() - на устарела. Вместо неё в WordPress есть wp_mail().

Чтобы wp_mail() заработала в вашем обработчике, в нём надо инициализировать ядро:

```
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php' );
```

Можно использовать плагин Contact Form 7, он работает через wp_mail().

Но основная проблема - у вас должны быть в DNS записи SPF, DKIM, DMARC. Нет их - все летит в спам.

Кроме того, лучше не со своего сервера отправлять (IP может быть в чёрном списке спамеров), а помощью relay, с SMTP-серверов yandex или google.

В этом вам поможет плагин [WP Mail SMTP от WPForms](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/).

Comment: `mail()` - не то, что бы устарело - это функция php  и использование её может быть опасно и просто не работать в нек случаях. `wp_mail()` решает много проблем с этим. А по поводу IP - нужно использовать нормальные хостинги, а не извращаться, лишний раз сливая  данные лишний всяким гуглояндексам ;) Ну так - плюс.

Answer (score 1):

создай email на своем хостинге, обычно хостеры предоставляют такую возможность бесплатно.

И пропиши email отправителя вместо Davydov-Event.

Тебя банят mail так как нет отправителя.